# How the scope for memcmp works when the struct has multiple strings?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, getprogramaccounts

Let's imagine I have this account and I want to filter all the Program Accounts by the author:

```
pub struct EntryBook {
    title: String,
    author: String
}
```

How would be the `offset` to target the author property?

```
const filteringBooks = await program.account.entryBook.all([
      {
          memcmp: {
              offset: 8 +    // Discriminator.
                      4 +    // Title string prefix.
                      ?????  // Title String 
                      4,     // Author string prefix.
              bytes: bs58.encode(Buffer.from('<author name>')),
          }
      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pack them into fixed lengths byte arrays. This is the downside of memcmp: you can't have variable length fields. The following is an easy way to do so:

```
pub fn pack_string_in_32_bytes(string: String) -> Result<[u8; 32]> {
    let string_in_bytes = string.as_bytes();

    if string_in_bytes.len() > 32 {
        return Err(error!(CustomProgramError::StringTooLong));
    }

    let mut bytes: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
    bytes[..string_in_bytes.len()].copy_from_slice(string_in_bytes);

    Ok(bytes)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make title a fixed length in order for the offset to work in this way. e.g. `title: [u8; 10]` Then just pad the end of the `title` string with empty space if it doesn't fill up the full fixed length.