# How to find the exact location of a string on an account using memcpm offset

Tags: solana-program, memcmp, offset

I have the following Rust code that structured a Solana account and test cases from another file using typescript:

```
const DISCRIMINATOR_LENGTH: usize = 8;
const PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH: usize = 32;
const TIMESTAMP_LENGTH: usize = 8;
const STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX: usize = 4; // Stores the size of the string.
const MAX_FIRST_NAME_LENGTH: usize = 30 * 4; // 30 chars max.
const MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH: usize = 30 * 4; // 30 chars max.
const MAX_EMAIL_LENGTH: usize = 20 * 4; // 20 chars max.
const MAX_PHONE_LENGTH: usize = 10 * 4;//10 char max

#[account]
pub struct Contact {
    pub author: Pubkey,
    pub timestamp: i64,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub phone: String,
}

impl Contact {
    const LEN: usize = DISCRIMINATOR_LENGTH
        + PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH // Author.
        + TIMESTAMP_LENGTH // Timestamp.
        + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_FIRST_NAME_LENGTH // first Name.
        + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH // last Name.
        + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_EMAIL_LENGTH // Email.
        + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_PHONE_LENGTH; //phone
}

 it('can filter tweets by first name', async () => {
    //const author = program.provider.wallet.publicKey;
    const name = bs58.encode(Buffer.from('Peter'));
    const contactAccounts = await program.account.contact.all([
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 52,
          bytes: name,
          }
        
      }
    ]);
    assert.equal(contactAccounts.length, 1);
    assert.ok(contactAccounts.every(contactAccount => {
      return contactAccount.account.firstName==='Peter'
    }))
  });
```

Finding the first name at the 52'th location is working but when I try to find the last name location @ 176 bytes (52+120+4) the test case can't find any account.

What would be the exact location of the last name, or email? I have a test case that created Peter and Jordan as first and last names respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Referencing one of the answers in this question: [How the scope for memcmp works when the struct has multiple strings?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/742/how-the-scope-for-memcmp-works-when-the-struct-has-multiple-strings/745#745)

Seems like you would need to add padding for any unused space:

> You would have to make title a fixed length in order for the offset to
> work in this way. e.g. title: [u8; 10] Then just pad the end of the
> title string with empty space if it doesn't fill up the full fixed
> length.

You can try something like this (referenced Candy Machine Program: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/candy-machine/program/src/processor/initialize.rs#L62):

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

const DISCRIMINATOR_LENGTH: usize = 8;
const STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX: usize = 4;
const MAX_FIRST_NAME_LENGTH: usize = 30 * 4;
const MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH: usize = 30 * 4;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod anchor_memcmp {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let data = &mut ctx.accounts.data;

        let mut array_of_zeroes = vec![0u8; MAX_FIRST_NAME_LENGTH - first_name.len()];
        let new_first_name = first_name + std::str::from_utf8(&array_of_zeroes).unwrap();
        data.first_name = new_first_name;

        array_of_zeroes = vec![0u8; MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH - last_name.len()];
        let new_last_name = last_name + std::str::from_utf8(&array_of_zeroes).unwrap();
        data.last_name = new_last_name;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(first_name: String, last_name: String)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [first_name.as_bytes(), last_name.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        space = FullName::LEN
    )]
    pub data: Account<'info, FullName>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[account]
pub struct FullName {
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
}

impl FullName {
    const LEN: usize = DISCRIMINATOR_LENGTH
        + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX
        + MAX_FIRST_NAME_LENGTH
        + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX
        + MAX_LAST_NAME_LENGTH;
}
```

Which seems to work with memcmp

```
describe("anchor-memcmp", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env())

  const program = anchor.workspace.AnchorMemcmp as Program<AnchorMemcmp>

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const tx = await program.methods.initialize("First", "Last").rpc()
  })

  it("First String", async () => {
    const name = bs58.encode(Buffer.from("F"))
    const accounts = await program.account.fullName.all([
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 8 + 4,
          bytes: name,
        },
      },
    ])
    console.log(accounts)
  })

  it("Second String", async () => {
    const name = bs58.encode(Buffer.from("L"))
    const accounts = await program.account.fullName.all([
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 8 + 4 + 120 + 4,
          bytes: name,
        },
      },
    ])
    console.log(accounts)
  })
})
```